# Java object declaration beyond the common idiom

Tags: java, oop

Generally, when a new object is created in Java it follows the idiom:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

where the `Object()` constructor matches the object type `Object`.

But what if it doesn't? I understand from the Oracle Docs on [creating objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) and [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) that the constructor must be in that object's class or one of its subclasses.  However, suppose we wanted to declare a new stack.  My first instinct would be:

```
Stack s1 = new Stack();
```

But I assume it's valid to do it this way, too:

```
Object s2 = new Stack(); //This
```

Is there a difference here?  What are we really saying about `s2`?  I'm guessing `s2` is simply an empty stack, but only has access to the `Object` class methods?  I'm not sure why someone would ever do this, but I want to solidify my understanding of the Java hierarchy.  Are there really *any* circumstances where someone would use a subclass's constructor when creating a new object?

Any and all informative responses will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has access to all of `Object`'s methods but executes the implementation of those methods that `Stack` provides.. This is a classic java (or any object oriented language) best practice; code to an interface not an implementation. (or in this case a superclass)

Comment: This question is definitely __not a duplicate__ of the one cited.

Comment: The right side of OP's examples are __not an interface__.  Thus, how can this question be about "coding to an interface?"

Comment: @user The term _interface_ in the expression _programming to an interface_ isn't used to represent Java's interface types. It's used to describe a contract that we can expect an object to fulfill. It just so happens that Java interfaces provide that, but so do class types (and their subtypes).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The question you cited actually has clarified a lot for me, and I guess my question is (conceptually) a subset of it. However, I can only see the benefit of this practice when you actually have an `interface` or if you have a custom `class` that extends methods to its subclasses.  So for my question above, you would only declare `Object s2 = new Stack()` if `s2` only needed the methods provided in `Object()`, but for performance (or by requirement) you want to treat it as a stack at runtime?

Comment: There's no performance gain. It's good programming practice. Always be the most generic you can be. If you don't need any `Stack` methods, use its parent type to hold the reference to the object.

Comment: Very cool! Got it. Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, if it's not something you're already doing, it's important to distinguish between a variable, an object, and a reference value. A variable (of a reference types) holds a reference value. A reference value references an object (it's more or less a pointer to an object). And an object is a data structure that has state and behavior.